# Count the total processes spawned using /proc/loadavg

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, process, proc

In a Red Hat Linux 8 operating system, I examined the output of `cat /proc/loadavg` and obtained "5.20 5.78 8.04 16/1596 1954863".
After 4 minutes, I rechecked the `/proc/loadavg` output and received "7.05 7.33 8.11 3/1605 2071966".
Now, I am calculating the difference between the last values from both outputs, which is 2071966 - 1954863 = 117103.

Does this mean that within a 4-minute interval, the system created 117103 new processes?

Comment: GlaxoSmithKline ? Anyway : Strictly speaking no ! It could even be much more if, within these 4 minutes the pidmax threshold had been reached. If you get grounds to believe this impossible then… your deduction is indeed correct.

Comment: Thanks. Can I get more accurate value for number of process forked with in an interval if I take /proc/stat 'processes' filed diff? Time2 processes - Time1 processes = total no. of processes in that time interval?

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I am calculating the difference between the last values from both
> outputs, which is 2071966 - 1954863 = 117103. Does this mean that
> within a 4-minute interval, the system created 117103 new processes?

No, it does **not necessarily** mean that, because of [the way pids are allocated](https://lwn.net/Articles/10246/). (*)
When pid reaches `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` the kernel will search for unallocated pids restarting from 300.

So, if it happened that, since last reboot, the system reached pid_max at least once, your calculus is just meaningless.
If however, you can reasonably assume that this is not possible then, yes, your calculus is indeed correct.

---

Discovering an update to your question in OP's comments, then yes : computing the difference of values reported in `/proc/stat/processes` at different times is definitely the way to go for getting a reliable information since [this value indicates](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

> Number of forks since boot

Please do notice the word ***forks*** explicitly mentioned. Which number actually represents the number of ***processes*** in its original meaning (and filename) and possibly yours.
**But this implicitly excludes threads created by multi-threaded processes**. (since these are not spawned by the `fork()` system call. And since a thread is the schedulable entity, its ID (Thread ID) is taken from the list of available PIDs.
As an example (numbers taken for the sole sake of simplicity, lines in chronological order) :

  10th (single threaded) process forked : PID = 10 TID = 10
  11th (multithreaded) process forked : PID = 11 TID = 11
    first thread spawned by PID11 : TID = 12
    second thread spawned by PID11 : TID = 13
  12th process forked : PID = 14 TID = 14

Then the calculus based on `/proc/stat/processes` will report **3**.
When the calculus based on `/proc/loadavg` would report 14 - 10 = 4 (+1 in order to take the extreme into account) = **5** actually reporting the number threads (assuming pidmax never reached).

As a conclusion : if you actually mean *processes* in its original meaning then the calculus based on `/proc/stat/processes` gives the result you want irrespective of any possible pidmax reached.
If what you meant was in fact the number of *threads*, then the calculus based on `/proc/loadavg` is the one you want **if you can assume that pidmax has never been reached by the system since boot time**, other wise, its just meaningless.

---

<sup>(*) Sample given for sole sake of simplicity. Things have indeed evolved since 2.5 kernels (gaining in efficiency) but the main idea remains identical.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the details. Here are the stats from our live server:

$ date; cat /proc/stat | grep processes
Tue Feb 13 07:18:45 UTC 2024
processes 3183977629

$ date; cat /proc/stat | grep processes
Tue Feb 13 07:22:56 UTC 2024
processes 3183999372

Taking the diff of ‘processes’:
 
    3183999372 – 3183977629 = 21743

So, my assumption here is that, in the interval of 4 minutes and 11 seconds, the system forked 21743 new processes. Please correct me if I’m wrong; otherwise, I can close this thread.

Comment: @GSK : I extended my answer for more explanation. Because at the end of the day, it depends on what you mean by processes. In short *processes* in its good old meaning ? Then yes your calculus is correct. If you in fact mean *threads* then not really. Please see my update.